# Efficiently rotate vector in 2D (and 3D)

Tags: linear-algebra, c++, monte-carlo, blas, cuda

I need to efficiently rotate a 2D (and 3D) vector in a CUDA kernel. I was thinking about generating random unitary rotation matrices. I don't need to know the angle, it just has to be randomly distributed.

Is there some clever way to avoid the computational complexity of the division and the square root for the norm? Or another way to rotate a vector?

I need this for a 2D GPU off-lattice Monte-Carlo simulation, but a 3D solution would be nice too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Comment: Are the vectors to be "randomly" rotated based at the origin?  If you want to achieve a specific distribution, say a uniform distribution, then it would be helpful to Readers to see your implementation using "the division and the square root" before they try to offer an equivalent that avoids these.

Comment: I want to represent hard shape molecules, I have two characteristic vectors: **r** (position vector) and **u** (normalized orientation vector). The shape of the molecules is generated by applying matrix transformations on these vectors. I want to rotate the molecule, with uniform probability, around **r**, which is the origin for **u**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the standard methods for random rotations in 3D (*Sphere Point Picking*) are listed on [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html). On a CPU, Marsaglia's method is quite efficient, because it avoids expensive $\sin$ and $\cos$ computations.

Marsaglia's method isn't really suitable for a GPU, because it sometimes rejects pairs of random numbers. If you have access to fast trigonometric functions, the approach of equation (6) to (8) at the [page linked above](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) probably works better.

[Circle point picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePointPicking.html) in 2D is simpler. In any case, I don't think you can avoid the computation of a vector norm / square root, which is often implemented in hardware nowadays. Drawing random numbers or computing trigonometric functions is probably significantly more expensive.